# Create XML file in Angular2 + TypeScript

Tags: xml, angular, typescript

I want to create XML document in angularjs + Typescript project.

I read about XMLWriter() but i ma not able to use it. I am getting error "Cannot find name XMLWriter"

Could please suggest a good way to create XML file.

Answer (score 0):

XMLWriter is the good way.

The problem is that you haven't added both a link reference and a require/import statement, so the compiler doesn't know XMLWriter.

Script Reference:

```
///<reference path="../typings/modules/XMLWriter/index.d.ts" />
```

Require statement:

```
var XMLWriter = require('XMLWriter');
```

Your next steps should be as follows:

1. Install [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings)
2. Install XMLWriter (via typings)
3. Add a [script reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) to XMLWriter
4. Add an [import/require statement](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) to load the XMLWriter module

Comment: Thanks Alon, I was going through some inbuilt interfaces and found XMLDocument() is present in Typescript.

Comment: i have added code to create XML using
var xmlDoc = new XMLDocument();

Comment: I have added code to create XML using 
var xmlDoc = new XMLDocument(); 
This code does not have any build error. however, at run time i am getting 
angular.js:13424 TypeError: Illegal constructor

Comment: @OnkarrajAmbatwar I'm glad I've managed to help you. As my answer was helpful for you, please accept this answer and vote up, Then please create a new question for your new problem.

Comment: Sure Alon. Could you please tell me , how to add typing in specific Visual studio project.

Comment: I am not able to find XMLWriter typings. Could you please tell me how to get that.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with this specific library, I just explained to you how to solve the "Cannot find name" error. Now you need to open a new question for each problem you have. When you accept an answer you get 2 reputation points.